# How does the CSS button hover animation work?

Tags: css, animation, hover

I am trying to understand these block of code for button-hovering effect yet still confused.

I can understand when mouse over the button the `.btn:hover::after`   kicks in and display the background(z=-1) button then expand it with   `transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);`

However when mouse pointer move away from the button, the background button also does "shrinking" effect seems like from `transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);` to normal size.  I just couldn't understand which line of code controls this mouse-away animation.

```
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;

}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-.3rem);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem  rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-.1rem);
  box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem  rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.btn--white {

  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
}

.btn::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.btn--white::after {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The secret lies in `transition: all 0.2s` in the `:link` / `:visited` of the button. **[`transition`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)** not only transitions **in to** the target state, but also **out from** the target state. Essentially, it's `transition` that's controlling both sides of the animation that you're seeing.

It's still the **[`transform`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)** that's applying the actual offset, but `transition` is responsible for smoothly fading back and forth on whether the `transform` is applied or not -- without `transition`, the animation would simply 'jump' between the two states.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-.3rem);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-.1rem);
  box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.btn--white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
}

.btn::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.btn--white::after {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn--white">Button</a>
```

Comment: TY.  would you please further explain (.btn--white)  and  (.btn--white::after)  behavior in this setting?

Comment: Sure. The regular `.btn--white` does nothing more than set a background colour  (and white is the default, so it really does nothing). The `.btn::after` creates a transitional border around the button, which gives it a pulsating effect. However, it doesn't set a colour, so it isn't visible. `.btn--white::after` adds the colour, so you see the pulsating effect in white. I assume it's done this way to allow you to specify what colour the pulsating effect should be, by choosing the relevant class. I've also updated my fiddle to actually include the `.btn-white` class to showcase the pulsation.

Comment: Thanks again.  I am trying to use simple and plain terms to describe these codes, please correct me if I am wrong:

Comment: with `.btn::after` we created a new  btn behind the link btn, but with `.btn:hover::after` how did css pick the new btn with z-index= -1 to act on? aint it suppose to pick on top layer element, the btn.link for hovering effect?